# Changing constraint multiplier using traits

Tags: ios, autolayout, constraints, adaptive-layout

I have several objects with a width of at least 75% of the screen width.
The issue is that they do not look as good on iPads or landscape mode.
I want to change the "75%" for different traits but couldn't figure out how.

I've looked at the details of the constraint and clicked on the PLUS icon:
[image]

After adding a variation, I see that I can change the constant but not the multiplier:
[image]

Anyone has any idea how this can be done elegantly?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have two different constraint one for regular width (iPad) and one for compact width (iPhone).
Then add a variation to install the constraint only for the trait you are interested in by checking / unchecking the Installed option.

Comment: Just don't understand, why Apple didn't add the possibility to add a custom trait like for `constant`.